# calling signal after fork

Tags: c, linux, fork, signals, signal-handling

Is there any difference between "code listing 1" and "code listing 2"? Because in Code Listing 1, the child process is able to catch the SIGTERM signal and exit nicely. But code listng 2 is terminating abruptly on SIGTERM signal.

I am using Linux and C.

**Code Listing 1**

```
if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("Could not attach signal handler\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
pid = fork();
```

**Code Listing 2**

```
pid = fork();
if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("Could not attach signal handler\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The strange part is that **in Code Listing 2, both child and parent process sets the signal handler for SIGTERM**. So, this is supposed to work. Isn't it?

Comment: I've just tested it, works fine for me. Both processes exit gracefully via stopChild() call in both cases.

Comment: Are you per chance calling fork() from within a thread?

Comment: Can you provide a full example program which exhibits the behaviour?

Comment: who sends the SIGTERM? It's not the parent, is it? *cough* race *cough* (if the answer is yes)

Comment: Not able to reproduce it with the same code today! Not sure what happened.

Comment: @Sabya, maybe ninjalj is right and you send the TERM signal from the parent process? In this case you really have a race here, and it could work only sometimes.

Comment: Exactly, it is the parent who is sending the SIGTERM.

Comment: @Sabya, but then it could happen that it sends the signal before the signal() call in the child is completed. That is what ninjalj meant by a race.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sending the SIGTERM from the parent, the end result depends on the order on which processes get scheduled.

If the child gets scheduled first, everything works:

```
                                                +---------------+
                                                | pid = fork(); |
                                                +-------+-------+
                   parent                               |                               child
                          +-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                 +-------------------------+--------------------------+
                          |                                 | if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {       |
                          |                                 |       printf("Could not attach signal handler\n"); |
                          |                                 |       return EXIT_FAILURE;                         |
                          |                                 | }                                                  |
                          |                                 +-------------------------+--------------------------+
                          |                                                           |
                          .                                                           .
                          .                                                           .
                          .                                                           .
                          |                                                           |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+                                |
| if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {       |                                |
|       printf("Could not attach signal handler\n"); |                                |
|       return EXIT_FAILURE;                         |                                |
| }                                                  |                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+                                |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
            +-------------+-------------+                                             |
            | if (pid > 0) {            |                                             |
            |       kill(pid, SIGTERM); |                                             |
            | }                         |                                             |
            +-------------+-------------+                                             |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
```

But if the paren gets scheduled first, the child may have not had time to setup the signal handler:

```
                                                +---------------+
                                                | pid = fork(); |
                                                +-------+-------+
                   parent                               |                               child
                          +-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
                          |                                                           |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+                                |
| if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {       |                                |
|       printf("Could not attach signal handler\n"); |                                |
|       return EXIT_FAILURE;                         |                                |
| }                                                  |                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+                                |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
            +-------------+-------------+                                             |
            | if (pid > 0) {            |                                             |
            |       kill(pid, SIGTERM); |                                             |
            | }                         |                                             |
            +-------------+-------------+                                             |
                          |                                                           |
                          .                                                           .
                          .                                                           .
                          .                                                           .
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                 +-------------------------+--------------------------+
                          |                                 | if (signal(SIGTERM, stopChild) == SIG_ERR) {       |
                          |                                 |       printf("Could not attach signal handler\n"); |
                          |                                 |       return EXIT_FAILURE;                         |
                          |                                 | }                                                  |
                          |                                 +-------------------------+--------------------------+
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
                          |                                                           |
```

This is called a *race condition*, because the end result depends on who gets to run first.

Comment: I don't think this was the problem because the parent process were given sleep of 10 seconds before it sends the signal. Anyway, I'm accepting this as the answer now as I can not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

First, signal() is deprecated, it's better to use [sigaction()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigaction.html). I don't think fork() is in danger of vanishing altogether since so many things use it, but sigaction() does provide a much nicer interface.

The behavior you are experiencing is commonly caused by calling fork() from within a thread. POSIX addresses this [specifically](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a
>   single thread. If a multi-threaded
>   process calls fork(), the new process
>   shall contain a replica of the calling
>   thread and its entire address space,
>   possibly including the states of
>   mutexes and other resources.
>   Consequently, to avoid errors, the
>   child process may only execute
>   async-signal-safe operations until
>   such time as one of the exec functions
>   is called. [THR]   Fork handlers may
>   be established by means of the
>   pthread_atfork() function in order to
>   maintain application invariants across
>   fork() calls.
>
> When the application calls fork() from
>   a signal handler and any of the fork
>   handlers registered by
>   pthread_atfork() calls a function that
>   is not asynch-signal-safe, the
>   behavior is undefined.

This means, rather than inheriting a copy of the parent's entire address space, you inherit only a copy of the calling *threads* address space, which doesn't contain your handlers. It might be conceivable that you are, indeed (perhaps even unwittingly) calling fork() from within a thread.

A child process gets a carbon copy of the parent's address space. The only difference with signals would be *pending* signals, which the child will not receive as it gets a signal set initialized to zero. But yes, it does get a copy of the handlers.

Comment: calling signal before the fork is actually the succesful one, so signal dispositions do get copied to the child, calling it after fork is the case that breaks, i.e. somehow calling signal in the child does not work.

Comment: @wich - that's why I'm very suspicious that fork() is being called in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to man fork:

> The fork(), fork1(), and forkall() functions  create  a  new process.  The  address  space of the new process (child processcess) is an exact copy of the address space of  the  calling process  (parent  process).  The  child process inherits the following attributes from the parent process:
>
> ...
>
> o  signal handling settings (that  is,  SIG_DFL,  SIG_IGN, SIG_HOLD, function address)

In the first example the signal handler will be copied from the context of the parent to the forked child. But I can not explain why in the second example setting the signal handler in the child would fail.

Comment: But in the second example signal() is called for both processes. So it should set the signal handler for the child process as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Sergey, exactly that's my doubt!

Comment: POSIX says that any _pending_ signals for the parent aren't sent to the child, it starts with a signal set initialized to zero. But, the child _should_ inherit the handlers. Calling fork() within a thread in the absence of pthread_atfork() might explain what the OP is experiencing, however.

Comment: @Sergey, @Sabya; indeed, still not sure what can cause the problem.

Comment: I'm at a loss, leaving the (edited) answer for reference on the fork.